# Get next date(YYYY-MM-DD) according to the input date string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-formatting

Consider, I have a date that format is (Year-Month-Date),

```
adate = "2020-10-02";
```

Now I would like to create a jQuery function that input `adate` and return the `next_date` such like below,

```
function make_next_date(adate) {
  next_date = adate + 1; //"2020-10-03"
  return next_date;
}
```

Function should be work properly for the following input date,

```
adate = "2021-05-31";
next_date = "2021-06-01";

adate = "2020-12-31";
next_date = "2021-01-01";

adate = "2021-02-28";
next_date = "2021-03-01";
```

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com library to handle date related things, otherwise you need to write a lot of code to handle various scenario eg. edge cases, invalid date etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just JavaScript. JavaScript has dates. jQuery is not relevant to date manipulation.

---

```js
function make_next_date(adate) {
  next_date = new Date(adate);
  next_date.setDate(next_date.getDate() + 1);
  return next_date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

[
  "2021-05-31",
  "2020-12-31",
  "2021-02-28",
].forEach(date => {
  console.log({
    date,
    out: make_next_date(date)
  });
});
```

Comment: I really like the way you've used `next_date.toISOString().split("T")[0]` 

Comment: needs improvement to handle this ```{
  "date": "2021-06-31",
  "out": "2021-07-02"
}```

Comment: "2021-05-31" is parsed as UTC, but *setDate* adds a local day, so in some cases for daylight saving, it won't add a full UTC day. You need to use UTC methods.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function make_next_date(adate) {
  const date = new Date(adate);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

  // YEAR
  const rYear = date.getFullYear();

  // MONTH
  let rMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  rMonth = rMonth < 10 ? `0${rMonth}` : rMonth;

  // DATE
  let rDate = date.getDate();
  rDate = rDate < 10 ? `0${rDate}` : rDate;

  return `${rYear}-${rMonth}-${rDate}`;
}

["2021-05-31", "2020-12-31", "2021-02-28"].forEach((date) => {
  console.log({
    date,
    out: make_next_date(date),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your string to date object.
And add 1.
Let  date = new Date();
date.SetDate(Date.parseDate(your string + 1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date class and padStart function to achieve it.

```js
let adate = "2020-10-02";

function make_next_date(adate) {
    const [year, month, day] = adate
        .split("-")
        .map(item => parseInt(item));

    const date = new Date(year, month, day);

    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        date.getMonth().toString().padStart(2, 0),
        date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, 0)
    ].join("-")
}

console.log(make_next_date(adate));
```

Also, there is a very useful date manipulating package called [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment). You can achieve it by just 3 lines of codes using moment.

```
const moment = require("moment");
const FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD";

let adate = "2020-10-02";

function make_next_date(adate) {
    return moment(adate, FORMAT)
        .add(1, "day")
        .format(FORMAT);
}
```

Comment: `moment.js` - 5670 lines of code that will save you from writing 7 lines of code :)